# How to fetch price for a specific date from GoogleFinance?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-finance, google-finance-api

I tried below syntax to fetch the close price of specific date:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE(<Symbol_Name>,"price","07/09/2020")
```

While it works perfectly for US stocks, the result for Indian stocks are incorrect. For example: if you query for July 9th, the stock quote is fetched from July 10th. See below screenshots:

US Stock

[image: Screenshot 1 - US Stock]

Indian Stock

[image: Screenshot 2 - Indian Stock]

How to make this work for all stock symbols irrespective of date or timezone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `GOOGLEFINANCE` docs:

> Dates passed into `GOOGLEFINANCE` are treated as noon UTC time. Exchanges that close before that time may be shifted by a day.

Considering that the [NSE closing time is](https://tradebrains.in/stock-market-timings-in-india/) **3:30 PM** at India timezone (**UTC +5:30**), that's before noon UTC time (**10:00 AM**). Therefore, it gets shifted by a day, as expected.

Modifying the spreadsheet timezone won't produce any change. The best option I see here is to keep track of which tickers will get shifted and ask for the previous day instead.

#### Reference:

- [GOOGLEFINANCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281)

Answer (score 0):

make sure that market was open on that day. you can check like this:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("nse:tcs", "all", "20/06/2020", TODAY(), "daily")
```

[image: 0]